# Have a Question to my SQL Query. It always duplicates my id that shoudl be unique

Tags: sql, oracle

Hei guys,
i made a sql query for work but it duplicates my document multiple times.

```
select
  dokid, doktyp, kontakt_id, verkn_kontakt_id, relatie_id, 
  onderwerp, dok_nam, 
  dok_bes,betrag, belegnr, gjahr, TANR, old_vertrouw_id, 
  erstellt_am, impuser, gebr_bew, docname 
from v_dok_xml 
inner join corsa7.poststuk on poststuk_id=dokid 
inner join v_alle_dokumente on dok_id=dokid 
where doktyp in ('RECH','HY_DOK','HY_INT','IM_DOK','IM_INT',
                 'INT_SO','SONST_DOK','VB_DOK','VB_IN') 
  and BELEGNR is not null 
  and (GJAHR ='2018' or GJAHR is null) and rownum <=50
  and $where 
order by erstellt_am desc
```

$where is for the output 
you can click choose two dates and the data between it will get printed

Comment: That's how `JOIN`s work. They match every rows from one table to one or more rows in the related table. Therefore, the same rows will show up multiple times when there are multiple matches.

Comment: How can i make the query that dokid is unique ? because i need to join into the other tables

Comment: You can: 1) Make sure you match with one row on the related tables **at most** using some tricky predicates; or 2) You can aggregate the rows using `GROUP BY` dokid; in this case you'll need to use functions such as `MIN()`, `MAX()`, etc. on all columns that do not depend directly from dokid.